# Order by datetime but other field no consecutive

Tags: mysql, database, sql-order-by

im not expert in MySQL and im wondering if this is even possible or if i should do it in php...

I want to order by datetime but separate by groups of ids

I have this table:

```
(SELECT created_at, id FROM table ORDER BY created_at)


2018-07-14 23:03:57    a
2018-07-15 01:15:25    a
2018-07-15 03:02:46    a

2018-08-02 06:00:14    b
2018-08-02 06:00:35    b
2018-08-02 06:00:38    b

2018-08-02 06:01:38    c
2018-08-02 06:01:41    c
2018-08-02 06:01:44    c
```

And i need the result like this:

```
2018-07-14 23:03:57 a
2018-08-02 06:00:14 b
2018-08-02 06:01:38 c

2018-07-15 01:15:25 a
2018-08-02 06:00:35 b
2018-08-02 06:01:41 c

2018-07-15 03:02:46 a
2018-08-02 06:00:38 b
2018-08-02 06:01:44 c
```

I have been trying and searching for so long now and cant find an answer of how to achieve this only with MySQL, if it is not possible i will have to do it in php.

Thank you guys! have a nice day

EDIT: i hace no clue how to do a nice table in stackoverflow, sorry :(

Comment: I am puzzled by your sample data and expected result - is your data really organised in 3 datetime,id per row? and why is datetime field quoted?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, i have no clue how to do nice things yet, i think now is more clear, separated by groups of 3 just because there are only 3 ids in the example,  just for best reading

Comment: If I had no clue how to format data, I think I'd just try randomly pressing all the buttons, just to see what happens

Comment: And what determines, which a/b/c entry is in which abc group? I mean the value `2018-07-14 23:03:57` could be in any of the 3 groups. Why in the first?

Comment: Thank you a lotf or the edit, and sorry.

Comment: @fancyPants Because is the first "a" in the rule order by "created_at" even when the ids are separated by groups they are still ordered by the date, hope i explained myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doable, but not pretty. The workflow is basically like this:

1. order by id and then created_at
2. include a row number that is reset when the id changes
3. in an outer query order by the row number, then created_at

The query would look like this (I think...untested):

```
SELECT id, created at 
FROM (
    SELECT id, 
    created_at,
    @rownum := IF(@prev_id != id, 1, @rownum + 1) AS rownum,
    @prev_id := id
    FROM table 
    , (SELECT @rownum := 0, @prev_id := NULL) var_init_subquery
    ORDER BY id, created_at
) sq
ORDER BY rownum, created_at, id
```

In MySQL 8 this can be done prettier with window functions, though.

I guess this should do it:

```
SELECT id, 
created_at,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (created_at PARTITION BY id) AS rownum
FROM table 
ORDER BY rownum, created_at, id
```

If it's not 100% correct syntax wise, please consult the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number

Comment: I have no words, thank you a lot, i really appreciate it, and indeed i modified some syntax but with the example and the link it was so easy to do it!

Comment: Yes! it worked perfectly without subquery, thanks again!